# Freely generated groups and homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ a set of its elements, such that for any group $F$ and any set $\{y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n\}$ of elements of $F$ there is one and only one homomorphism $h: G \rightarrow F$ such that $h(x_i)=y_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Then $G$ is freely generated by the set $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$.

The other way round is quite easy to prove. To prove this one, the first thing that comes to one's mind is of course to let $F$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by the set $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$, and the elements $y_i$ to be the $x_i$ themselves. This yields a homomorphism $h: G \rightarrow F$ such that $h_{|F}=id_F$. This in turn yields that $G$ is the semidirect product of $F$ and $ker(h)$. I miss some point, and I can't get any further.

---

Well, folks, I beg your pardon for bothering you with such a trivial question. I can't believe I didn't see the answer at once. Sometimes one just can't see the most elementary things. Please, correct me if the following proof is wrong.

Let $F$ and $h$ be as stated before, $i$ the inclusion of $F$ into $G$. Then $k=i\circ h$ is an endomorphism of $G$ such that $k(x_i)=x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. If $F\neq G$ and $i_G$ is the identity of $G$ then $k \neq i_G$.  But by hypothesis $i_G$ is the only endomorphism $f$ of $G$ such that $f(x_i)=x_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: you may consider F to be the free group on n elements and maps $x_i$ to $i$. also, you should use the uniqueness hypothesis...

Comment: Your first sentence is often used as the definition of what it means for $G$ to be freely generated by the $x_i$. So what definition are you using?

Comment: Assumably an explicit construction, e.g. as finite words in $x_i,$ $x_i^{-1}$ with concatenation product.

Comment: _@Derek Holt_ That the elements generate _G_ and that they don't satisfy any relation save the ones satisfied by any sets of elements in any group.

Comment: _@Derek Holt_ By the way, to show that the elements $x_i$ are "free" in the meaning I stated before is easy.

Comment: _@user126154_, _@Kevin Carlson_ The context assumes a simpler approach, as the existence of free groups has not come into question yet.

Comment: Hm. I was in the middle of writing an answer that uses the existence of free groups. Your approach won't work as stated: for instance if $G=\mathbb Z/2\times\mathbb Z/3,F=\mathbb Z/2$ there's a unique homomorphism $G\to F$ sending $(1,0)\mapsto 1$ but $G$ is not freely generated, nor even generated, by $(1,0)$.

Comment: _@Kevin Carlson_ I thought about direct products as well. That's why I couldn't get anywhere that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wanted to take $F$ to be a free group on $x_1,...,x_n$, but to get around your restriction of not assuming that there *are* free groups here is a different approach. Consider a presentation for $G$ as $\langle x_1,...,x_n,(w_m)_{m\in M}: (r_j)_{j\in J}\rangle$ where the $r_j$ are relations. Suppose some subset $S$ of the $r_j$ involve only the $x_i$. Then there exists no homomorphism fixing the $x_i$ from $G$ to the group with presentation identical to that of $G$ except for the removal of relations in $S$. This contradicts our assumption, and so $S$ is empty, that is, all the relations involve some of the $w_j$. So we've shown that the subgroup of $G$ generated by the $x_i$ is free on them.

What remains is to show that $M$ is empty. Construct a group $H$ generated by the $w_m$ with relations gotten from the $r_j$ by setting $x_i=e.$ Consider the list $y_1=...=y_n=e$ of elements of $H$. The trivial homomorphism $G\to H$ sending every element to $e$ is certainly a homomorphism of the kind required by the assumption about $G$. But I claim the map $\varphi$ described by $\varphi(x_1)=...=\varphi(x_n)=e,\varphi(w_m)=w_m\forall m\in M$ is also a homomorphism, which obviously satisfies the condition on the image of the $x_i$. Indeed, it's enough to check that $\varphi$ sends every relation to $e$. But since all the $x_i$ are sent to $e$ already the only remaining nontrivial relations are those we cooked into the definition of $H$. So we apparently have two different homomorphisms to $H$ sending the $x_i$ to $e,$ which would contradict our assumption that such a homomorphism should be unique. Thus in fact each $w_m=e$ in $H$ and thus so too in $G$.

Comment: I had briefly thought about the null map instead, but I didn't develop. I'll check your proof carefully, but at first sight sounds right.

Comment: _@Kevin Carlson_ Thanks a lot. Sorry, I had incidentally posted the other comment before finishing to write it. I wonder, can't the proof that the $x_i$ are free be simpler? That is, if there were any relation on them in $G$, then there would be at least one group $F$ and elements $y_i$ in it such that no homomorphism as requested were possible. Also, $G$ might not a priori have a finite set of generators, but surely one can replace the $w_i$ with a generic set of elements.

Comment: To your first question: there's no need for an induction. Actually that's also how to fix my finite generation assumption: in both cases where I constructed a new group using one relation or one generator, use all of them at once.

Comment: Wonderful! Perfect! I was just thinking about how to modify your proof but you beat me. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: No problem. Would have left the alterations to you but it was wronger than I wanted to leave out in public as it stood.

Comment: Wouldn't it be even simpler taking $H$ as the subgroup of $G$ generated by the $w_m$? This way one doesn't need to construct $H$, all the possible relations being automatically satisfied.

Comment: Before we know that the $w_m$ are trivial there's no reason there should be a homomorphism of $G$ onto the subgroup generated by the $w_m$. For instance consider $\langle x,w: xw=e\rangle$. $w\mapsto w,x\mapsto e$ is not a homomorphism.

Comment: Yes, I had thought that too in the meanwhile, only not at 4am! I was too quick in writing the preceding comment, but your counterexample doesn't work, for $x_iw_j=e$ would imply that $w_j$ is already in the subgroup generated by the $x_i$. $x_i^2w_j^2=e$ does work though.

Comment: I wanted to use a subgroup of $G$ because I was concerned about existence: assuming that of a group with generators and relations isn't basically the same as assuming that of a free group?

Comment: I understand the concern, but I don't currently see how to get around it. The condition on $G$ only permits maps *out* of $G$, and there's no reason for $G$ to map out to its subgroups in general. How do you define the subgroup generated by a set of elements without having shown that a presentation uniquely specifies a group? I suppose you could exhibit my group $H$ as a quotient of $G$. That may be the best solution, but will require constructing the kernel of the quotient map more explicitly than I did.

Comment: In the meanwhile I found a simpler answer. Look at the update in the post. Do you think it is correct?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's the right solution! I feel silly, because that's exactly the kind of solution I should have looked for: it's using that being a free group is what's called a "universal property." Good stuff.

Comment: But to answer your question, it is just the smallest subgroup that contains all the elements.

Comment: I feel a bit ashamed...